# Error code "Can't finde project or library" in vba

Tags: vba, excel, select, case

I'm making a vba project with some userforms. I want the people to click the macro button, then need to choose their initials, then by togglebutton click the weeks they want to go on holiday and then click transfer. So far i've done, that if they click one their initials, the value will be printed to a cell. The next userform (userform2), will need to look for the value, to determin wich row the values will be printed in.

But i get an error, on my Select case code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim score As Integer, result As String
    score = ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Value

    Select Case score
        Case Is = "CTK"
            result = Something
        Case Is = "MogM"
            result = Something1
        Case Is = "KSJI"
            result = Something2
        Case Is = "TSLR"
            result = Something3
        Case Is = "JOHQ"
            result = Something4
        Case Is = "OLGJ"
            result = Something5
        Case Is = "CBJN"
            result = Something6
        Case Is = "JVLK"
            result = Something7
        Case Is = "JFP"
            result = Something8
        Case Is = "EVAD"
            result = Something9
        Case Is = "TKUP"
            result = Something10
        Case Else
        MsgBox ("Didn't find anyone with these init")
Range("A20").Value = result
End Select

End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

End Sub
```

I solved the coding, but now i got a new question. Is it possible to simplify it?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim score As Integer, result As String
    score = ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Value

         Select Case score
            Case Is = "1"
                result = "CTK"
            Case Is = "2"
                result = "MogM"
            Case Is = "3"
                result = "KSJI"
            Case Is = "4"
                result = "TSLR"
            Case Is = "5"
                result = "JOHQ"
            Case Is = "6"
                result = "OLGJ"
            Case Is = "7"
                result = "CBJN"
            Case Is = "8"
                result = "JVLK"
            Case Is = "9"
                result = "JFP"
            Case Is = "10"
                result = "EVAD"
            Case Is = "11"
                result = "TKUP"
            Case Else
            MsgBox ("Didn't find anyone with these init")
End Select
Range("A20").Value = result

'CTK opportunities
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton1 = True Then Range("B4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton2 = True Then Range("C4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton3 = True Then Range("D4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton4 = True Then Range("E4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton5 = True Then Range("F4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton6 = True Then Range("G4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton7 = True Then Range("H4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton8 = True Then Range("I4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton9 = True Then Range("J4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton10 = True Then Range("K4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton11 = True Then Range("L4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton12 = True Then Range("M4").Value = "X"

'Next person


Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a reference in tools> References, nothing here needs a reference, so the problem must be in the "something"

Comment: Now it says type 13 mismatch @tompreston. And it's the score = ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Value i get an error on now.

Comment: You have Dim'd score as an integer, but then used a text comparison for the case. This will be the mismatch

Comment: (a) Flephal correctly identifies that you will get a Type Mismatch when comparing the `Integer` variable `score` to a `String`, but you will also get that error on the line before if `ActiveSheet.Range("A19").Value` does not contain a number.  (b) You are also, in the `Case Else` assigning `Range("A20").Value` to `result`, but you have never set `result` to anything - so it will always set the value to an empty string.  Probably that line should be done **outside** the `Case` statement.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. I edited the code, to the code i got now and is there anyway to simplify the if statements?

Comment: Btw i know that `Range("A20").Value = result` is unnecessary, but i used it to see if the code worked :-)